# In the App Settings on Facebook Developer, where is the "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" section?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to create the tab for an app I just made, but step-by-step instructions say to find the "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" section and select "Page Tab". When I go to the settings for the app, there is no such section there. The instructions appear to be old as the pictures they provide do not match the current design of Facebook Developer.

I would like to know where and how I can create the tab for the app.

Comment: I too am looking for this.

Comment: Me too, if any of you above found it. please inform me ( @WMios )